# DBUnitのテーブル比較結果について

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

現在、DBUnitを採用するか迷っていまして

DBUnitのassertEqualsメソッドで 
テーブルオブジェクト同士の比較ができると思いますが 
データ値が異なる場合、カラム毎にエラー情報は出るのでしょうか？

例えば、以下の場合

実テーブル 
ID:1 
name:本１ 
suryo:2

検証元テーブル 
ID:1 
name:本１ 
suryo:3

** suryo 予測 3、 実際 2** 
のようなイメージ

知りたい理由： 
「比較したオブジェクトが異なります」だけのメッセージだけの場合、 
何が違うかわからないためです。

調査する時間がなく 
知っている方が、いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBUnitはテーブル同士の比較も可能です。(前提条件として、双方PrimaryKeyを設定しておくことがあります）

ご懸念の点についても、割と詳細に出してくれます。

- テーブル名
- 行番号(0開始)
- カラム名
- 期待する値
- 実際の値
- (比較できる場合は)期待値と実値の違い

アサーションエラーのトレース例を貼りますので、参考にしてください。

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: value (table=sample2, row=1, col=storeText) expected:<[anoth]er> but was:<[us]er>
    at org.dbunit.assertion.JUnitFailureFactory.createFailure(JUnitFailureFactory.java:39)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DefaultFailureHandler.createFailure(DefaultFailureHandler.java:97)
    …(中略)…
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

文字列同士で比較して違うところを示してくれますね。
動作確認は以下の環境で行いました。

- DBUnit 2.5.1
- MySQL 5.5.34

参考になれば幸いです。